# Spreading out input elements evenly inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have an app with a nested div structure, looking something like this:

```
<div>
     <div style="width:10%"></div>
     <div style="width:90%">
         <div style="width:25%"> 
             <input />
             <input />
             <input />
             <input />
         </div>
         <div style="width:25%"> (2-4 inputs) </div>
         <div style="width:25%"> (2-4 inputs) </div>
         <div style="width:25%"> (2-4 inputs) </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to automatically calculate and spread out all the input tags evenly within the div element? I have read about relative-absolute positioning, css-calc, tablerow-tablecell positioning, but can't seem to figure out how to apply them to achieve the result I need.

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Comment: it depends what browsers do you have to support?

Comment: The easiest way would be flexbox. But if you need to support IE pre v10, then don't go the flexbox route. Take a look at the [support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: exactly why I am asking

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies. I don't have the need for IE browser support. Will check out flexbox! :)